# Deploy Back end server step in Play billing sample app

Tags: firebase, in-app-billing, firebase-cli

I've followed all the steps in [here](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiJava) to get the "Classy Taxi: Google Play Billing Subscriptions Android App Java Sample" running, however on the last step I'm very confused, it´s not clear to me as to how I´m supposed to deploy the back-end, here are the steps:

These are steps to build the backend server code located [here](https://github.com/FranTar1991/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer)

1. Make sure you have installed Node.js, npm, and Firebase CLI.
2. Run `npm install` to install dependencies.
3. Configure Cloud Functions for Firebase with your Android app and subscription products:

```
firebase use --add {your_firebase_project_id}
firebase functions:config:set app.package_name="your_android_application_id"
firebase functions:config:set app.basic_plan_sku="your_basic_subscription_product_sku_id"
firebase functions:config:set app.premium_plan_sku="your_premium_subscription_product_sku_id"
```

4. Run `firebase deploy` to deploy your backend to Cloud Functions for Firebase.

On the steps it´s not clear as to how the server will be deployed, it only mentioned the app id and the products SKU´s but not the code for the server so I need help clarifying that, please. I would like to see steps by step how to deploy the server.

This is what I´m currently doing:
1. Go to the root folder for the server
2. Open cmd from that folder
3. run the commands listed on the docs.
4. then I get this error:

```
=== Deploying to 'billing-project-c9f03'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\frank\Desktop\Billing app\ClassyTaxiServer\server\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\frank\Desktop\Billing app\ClassyTaxiServer\server\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\frank\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-13T01_21_30_198Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code429496323
```

But I see the package.json file on the root folder.

Comment: As the last step says: "Run `firebase deploy` to deploy your backend to Cloud Functions for Firebase." This is the step that deploys the code for your backend API to [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

Comment: I can see that, but what I'm confused about is that I don't see from which directory I need to run that from to deploy the server. For example with cloud functions I know that I can deploy the functions from the functions folder and that all my functions live in the index.js file. Also when I run the commands previous to firebase deploy I get a message stating that I need to run firebase init and if I follow the workflow to deploy cloud functions the server is not deployed because there isn't an index.js file.

Comment: @frantardencilla you should have updated the `firebase.json` previously, as I've explained in my answer... directory `server` is quite obviously wrongful; this has to be `.` (the current directory). And also `web` should be `webapp` (for the hosting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Firebase CLI [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deployment). This should be the project's root directory `ClassyTaxiServer`; assuming that you've ran all previous steps successfully, before attempting to `firebase deploy`.  [`firebase.json`](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/master/ClassyTaxiServer/firebase.json) knows what to do... however, that file is the actual problem; see [PR #289](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/pull/289/commits/db3a7c00fc0ceda08762a1fcc07023058e92b1f0).

Update `firebase.json` to this version and it should work out:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "."
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "webapp",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ ]
  }
}
```